# С чем может быть связана медленная отрисовка дерева каталогов на DLNA клиенте?

Tags: сеть, роутер

Заменил недавно старый роутер на гигабитник Mikrotik RB951G-2HnD.
Все отлично, кроме одной интересной проблемы. Есть у меня в локальной сети - PC с установленным DLNA сервером (twonky) и клиент для него в виде телевизора LG.

Который на старом роутере отлично крутил кинцо мне пару лет. Но после замены роутера на Mikrotik, TV стал по долгу строить дерево каталогов медиа-контента, для построения каталога, бедный TV зависает минуты на 2, когда как на старом роутере строил за пару секунд. Такие зависания происходят при каждом смене каталога на новый, после их построения дальше ходит по каталогам естественно быстро до выключения TV.
При этом стрим видео происходит идеально даже - fullHD.

Настройки Mikrotik дефолтные, натыканые в QuickSet.

Соединение сервера и клиента осуществляется по кабелю.

Приветствуются любые идеи с чем может быть связана такая проблема и как это можно пофиксить.

Answer (score 3):

Самый очевидный вариант - полноценного гигабита по проводу не поднялось, идут ошибки. Для начала посмотреть статистику пакетов на интерфейсах - сбросить ошибки, понагружать сеть и посмотреть изменение количества ошибок. Вполне возможно что раньше была сеть достаточно хорошая для 100 мегабит, но сейчас идут потери пакетов на гигабите, сыплются ошибки.

Как вариант - зажать скорость интерфейсов на 100 мегабит и посмотреть, а не станет ли лучше. Потому что скорость установившегося скачивания потока, плюс буферизация - не даст заметить проблемы, а вот куча мелких фреймов, в диалоговом режиме, которые перезапрашиваются при ошибке повторно (плюс таймауты) - как раз даёт примерно такую картину.

Еще бы исключил из виноватых сервер, начал бы со странного - запустить DLNA клиент локально на компе, чтобы убедиться, что комп локально, то есть без микротика, всё еще работает быстро. Ну или напрямую воткнуть комп в телевизор, коротким шнуром, чтобы исключить влияние каналов связи.
Могло параллельно произойти что угодно - обновление прошивки телевизора, обновление версии сервера, резкое увеличение медиатеки, антивирус капризничать начал, жесткий диск затупил и проч.

Финальный этап - запустить на интерфейсах [захват пакетов](http://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Tools/Packet_Sniffer), нагрузить сеть, а потом на компе файл захвата внимательно рассматривать в Wireshark, может быть что-то хорошее будет видно.

В любом случае 2 компонента - убедиться, что сеть работает хорошо, убедиться что клиент/сервер работает хорошо, а дальше уже искать виноватого в микротике.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Проблема была в телевизоре, все остальные клиенты DLNA работали отлично,
(телевизор SONY, десктоп пк клиенты, мобайл)
Решилась проблема просто установкой на Mikrotik->IP->UPnP: allow-disable-external-interface в yes .
Без понятия правда что это за параметр и зачем он был так нужен DLNA клиенту на телевизоре LG.